# Log apache requests from localhost in different file

Tags: apache, logging, centos

I have a centos 6.7 with Apache/2.2.15. Apache log requests from my website in /var/log/httpd/mywebsite.log. I also use an api and to aceess the api I use mywebsite.com/api. In api, the request is made by localhost. The problem is thet we need to save the logs separatly. I want to have to log files. One for mywebsite.com/api and one for mywebsite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^127\.0\.0\.1 islocal
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!islocal
CustomLog logs/access_log_local common env=islocal
```